# Is there some sort of or statement in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is there some sort of or statement in jQuery? I used

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navi-button , #navigation").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#navigation").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work well and I think an or statement would do better.

It's supposed to make a navigation menu appear by hovering over a button.

Every time I hover over it it starts then ends and then starts again.

https://jsfiddle.net/d5LxjL7n/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
css:

```
#navigation {
  display: none;
}
```

js:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#navi-button").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#navigation").fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wk98avws/

Comment: I updated my original fiddle I forgot to add some things

Comment: what things are you talking about?

Comment: Check now I made sure it changed this time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<button id="navi-button">nav</button>
<div id="navigation">
   This is navigation
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation{   display:none; }
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navi-button").hover(function() {
        $("#navigation").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/sum1/pen/YWKYMo